# Copy constructor vs std::initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++

Imagine that we have:

```
struct S {
  struct S {
  S() { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
  S(const S&) { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
  S(S&&) { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
  ~S() { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }

  S(std::initializer_list<S>) { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};
```

Which constructors should be called when `S s2{S{}};`?
Is it ok that gcc and clang have different behavior?

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/qQxyp5

gcc (trunk) output:

```
S::S()
S::S(std::initializer_list<S>)
S::~S()
S::~S()
```

clang (trunk) output:

```
S::S()
S::~S()
```

Comment: Both behaviors are technically correct, but clang's is more optimized. gcc is performing [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) on the inner string, and then [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) on the outer string. clang is seeing that `s2` is constructed by a temp inner string and [elides the temp away](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), constructing `s2` directly. See [When and why would I use -fno-elide-constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086573/)

Comment: The godbolt link is a nice supplement, but including the output in the question makes it self contained whether the link is valid or not.  And I don't have to click on a link and try to figure out the relevant parts of that page.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "*clang is seeing that s2 is constructed by a temp inner string and elides the temp away*" I don't see anything in the standard which would allow for such elision. Guaranteed elision in C++17 is based on prvalues being used to initialize objects, but list-initialization defies that because it would, for class types, trigger section 3.6, which is to call a constructor. And the common rules for elision don't list the case of list initialization from a prvalue as a possible case of elision.

Answer (score 2):

GCC is correct here; list initialization does not allow for copy elision in C++17.

If you had done `S s2(S{});`, this would be required to only call `S`'s default constructor, due to [[dcl.init]/17.6.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.1):

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object. [ Example: T x = T(T(T())); calls the T default constructor to initialize x.  — end example ]

However, that only applies to copy initialization and direct initialization.

Doing `S s2{S{}};` is list-initialization, which is its own entirely separate form of initialization with its own rules. Since `S` is not an aggregate, [[dcl.init.list]3.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.6) would take over, which says:

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]).

Calling a constructor means invoking a specific function with a specific set of parameters. And that means that the prvalue `S{}` must be used to initialize the parameter to the selected constructor. Which means you *have* to call the copy/move constructor.

Regular, non-guaranteed, elision aren't allowed either. [class.copy.elision]/1 gives the 3 circumstances under which elision is allowed: `return localVariableName`, `throw localVariableName`, and `catch(TypeName)` if the catch matches what was thrown. This case is obviously none of these, so it doesn't qualify for regular elision.